# Dataset Query using Composition fails but RightComposition works - why?

Tags: bugs, dataset

V10.1 on Win764 Enterprise.

In this (**CORRECTED**) example the two Queries may be compounded into one using RightComposition sucessfully...

```
Dataset[{<|"A" -> 1|>, <|"A" -> 2|>}][Query[Select[#["A"] == 1 &]] /* Query[Select[IntegerQ[#["A"]] &]]]
```

However using Composition (@*) instead fails.  Why?

In this case f[g[x]] === g[f[x]] no?

Comment: Your code has a syntax error - I think there shouldn't be a `]` after `Select[#"A"`.

Comment: Your code seems weird... Why would you do `Dataset[...][Query[Select[#"A"]==1&]]`? That doesn't seem right. Did you mean `Dataset[...][Select[#A == 1 &]]`?

Comment: @StefanR - yes - apologies, there were some errors in the question I have now corrected.

Comment: Reported "officially" to Wolfram.

Comment: Note that this issue is fixed in Mathematica 10.2.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the documentation only mentions query operator composition using `/*`.  It may be that `@*` is not supported or has unrevealed semantics.

However, it seems reasonable to assume that `@*` would work similarly to `/*`.  If so, then this looks like a query compilation bug in both versions 10.0.2 and 10.1.0.

**Analysis**

As noted in the question, the query using `/*` compiles successfully:

```
Normal@Query[Query[Select[#["A"] == 1 &]] /* Query[Select[IntegerQ[#["A"]] &]]]
(* Select[#1["A"] == 1 &] /* Select[IntegerQ[#1["A"]] &] *)
```

... but the same query expressed by swapping the operators and using `Composition` fails to compile:

```
Normal@Query[Query[Select[IntegerQ[#["A"]] &]] @* Query[Select[#["A"] == 1 &]]
(* Failure[] *)
```

An error occurs in this simpler query as well:

```
Normal@Query[Query["a"] /* Query["b"]]
(* GeneralUtilities`Slice["a", "b"] *)

Normal@Query[Query["b"] @* Query["a"]]
(* Missing[PartInvalid, "a"] *)
```

And this even simpler query yields a baffling result:

```
Normal@Query[f /* g]
(* f /* g *)

Normal@Query[g @* f]
(* g[f[Identity]] *)
```

The result `Missing[PartInvalid, "a"]` in particular suggests that perhaps there is an evaluation leak or other improper operator structural transformation somewhere in the compilation process.

`@*` is undocumented, so it seems unlikely but possible that it has some unrevealed semantics that are intentionally different from being the "reverse" of `/*`.  My own guess is that it is a bug.

Comment: Yup it is a bug, already reported to me. Thanks. Will fix for 10.1.1, which is a month or two away.

Comment: All of these are now fixed in 10.2 (formerly known as 10.1.1). Although clearly 10.2 took longer than we expected.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a square brace in the wrong place your code.

```
Query[Select[#"A"] == 1 &]
```

should be

```
Query[Select[#"A" == 1 &]]
```

These both work:

```
Dataset[{<|"A" -> 1|>, <|"A" -> 2|>}][Query[Select[#"A" == 1 &]] /* Query[Select[IntegerQ[#["A"]] &]]]

Dataset[{<|"A" -> 1|>, <|"A" -> 2|>}][Query[Select[IntegerQ[#["A"]] &]]@*Query[Select[#"A" == 1 &]]]
```

Comment: You're right, trying to work out if I still have a problem...

Comment: After "These both work" the first one succeeds, the second one fails.